# Problem with query string and extract values

Tags: c#, query-string, sqlcommand

I can't extract the values through a *query* and insert them into `textbox`es

Where am I going wrong?

```
 Request.QueryString.Get("ID_Persona");

 string query = "SELECT ID,Nome,Cognome,Email,CodiceFiscale FROM Persona WHERE ID = @id";

 using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConnection"].ConnectionString))
       {         
           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID","");
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nome", TextBox1.Text);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cognome", TextBox15.Text);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", TextBox20.Text);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CodiceFiscale", TextBox22.Text);

           con.Open();

           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
```

Comment: what is the behavior you are experiencing now? Does it retrieve the the columns you want? you just need to assign the values to the textboxes now?

Comment: I need to enter the database values in these texboxes. I identify the line with the id

Comment: You used `ExecuteNonQuery`. That doesn't return any data. Use ExecuteReader instead, or a microORM like Dapper to make the code simpler

Comment: with ExecuteReader it doesn't work the same

Comment: @Elmachico, have you tried my example below?

Comment: There is no point passing a `@Nome` parameter that isn't being used.

Comment: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID","");` I doubt if query return anything for **empty** `ID`

Comment: @Elmachico please try the updated answer, was probably an error that I was using while for reading multiple records

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `ExecuteReader` to read values, something like this:

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConnection"].ConnectionString;
string query = "SELECT ID,Nome,Cognome,Email,CodiceFiscale FROM Persona WHERE ID = @id";
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
    {
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Request.QueryString.Get("ID_Persona"));
      con.Open();
      using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
      {
          if (rdr.Read())
          {
              //IDTextBox? = rdr["Id"].ToString(),
              TextBox1.Text = rdr["Nome"].ToString(),
              TextBox15.Text = rdr["Cognome"].ToString(),
              TextBox20.Text= rdr["Email"].ToString(),
              TextBox22.Text= rdr["CodiceFiscale"].ToString(),    
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: can you `debug` and see what part is not working? is an exception being thrown?

Comment: No it does not throw any exception, now I tell you in the debug what I see

Comment: `if (rdr.Read())` instead of `while (rdr.Read())` since you want to read only one record

Comment: the id is taken from a listview where there is the change key and I pass that in a quey string

Comment: yep as others have said, make sure you are passing in an ID as the question has an empty string, I thought you did that on purpose, but maybe not

Comment: JohnChris Thank you so much your method works, you gave me a big hand, I also thank all the others

Comment: @Elmachico was a team effort indeed, no problem

Comment: @JohnChris to the next friend, I will not easily forget you!

Answer (score 2):

You should use a [`ExecuteReader()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader?view=netframework-4.8) instead of `ExecuteNonQuery()` since `ExecuteNonQuery` is meant for DML operations. Again, you need only the ID value to be passed then why you are passing unnecessary parameters to your query. Remove them all. An example below

```
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", reader["Email"]));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I can see several issues:

1. You should use `ExecuteReader()` instead of `ExecuteNonQuery()`
2. You should provide just `1` parameter - `@ID`; I doubt if it should have an *empty* value.
3. You should wrap `IDisposable` into `using`

**Code:**

```
   string query = 
     @"SELECT ID,
              Nome,
              Cognome,
              Email,
              CodiceFiscale 
         FROM Persona 
        WHERE ID = @id";

   using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(...))
   {         
       con.Open();

       using SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con) 
       {
           // I doubt if you want empty Id here. 
           // I've assumed you want to pass ID_Persona
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Request.QueryString.Get("ID_Persona")); 

           using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
           {
               if (reader.Read()) 
               {
                   TextBox1.Text  = Convert.ToString(reader["Nome"]); 
                   TextBox15.Text = Convert.ToString(reader["Cognome"]); 
                   TextBox20.Text = Convert.ToString(reader["Email"]); 
                   TextBox22.Text = Convert.ToString(reader["CodiceFiscale"]);   
               }
           }
       }
  }
```